# How to get started using sails.js, OrientDB and Tinkerpop / Gremlin

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, waterline, gremlin, tinkerpop

Using sails.js as our main node.js framework we got a good toolset, having sails.js waterline (ORD/ODM) connected to OrientDB with https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb.

In order to dig deeper with graph traversals, we want to use Tinkerpop which is available for OrientDB and (somehow) for node.js using https://github.com/RedSeal-co/ts-tinkerpop.

**Questions:**

- Has someone tried to integrate Tinkerpop / Gremlin with sails.js /
  Waterline?
- Combining the three options: Native OrientDB SQL, Waterline (using Oriento/OrientJS or sails-orientdb) AND Gremlin?
- Is there any experience regarding performance? (This one is not very
  encouraging: [OrientDB SQL vs Gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260952/orientdb-sql-vs-gremlin))
- Are there any (npm) packages to prefer over others?
- Or should we go with Gremlin embedded into native OrientDB-SQL-ish queries?

Comment: The quickest option seem Gremlin-queries via OrientDB-SQL.